Need a Regex Query for SQL to capture Timestamp
I am trying to capture Timestamp and the next section as timestamp_time from column data (in Bold)
[{"type":"DEPRECATION","reason":"\u003cp\u003eSales force instance of IDG has been deprecated. Schema and tables in Data Lake are deprecated.\u003c/p\u003e","timestamp":"09-Apr-2024 21:31:27 +0000","userEmail":"Shobhit_Gupta@intuit.com","propagatedFrom":"hive_db:ent_sfdc_idg_dwh(cb2a922b-85fe-4eb6-ab4d-60865d22fe57)"}]
I tried writing query like
SELECT name,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(deprecations, r'\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4}') AS extracted_timestamp
FROM mdr_export.hive_table limit 10;
However this is giving error- Specified regexp group (1) cannot exceed 0
The regex is correct and tested. Any help here to rectify the query would be greatly appreciated
